# Android ViewModel load more data when Fragment scroll reaches end

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I'm new to Android so not sure how to do this

I have a fragment with a list view. I need the fragment to be able to detect that the list view scroll reached the end and for that I can do the following

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(onScrollListener());
private OnScrollListener onScrollListener() {
  return new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
      int threshold = 1;
      int count = listView.getCount();

      if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition()>=count-threshold&&pageCount < 2) 
        {
          Log.i(TAG, "loading more data");
          // Execute LoadMoreDataTask AsyncTask
          getDataFromUrl(url_page2);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, in the code above we use a local method getDataFromUrl and instead of that I need to tell the ViewModel to load more data and update the fragment with LiveData

Comment: Instead of scrolling to the end, consider loading more data before user reaches the end. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView Also, look into recyclerview instead of listview. To tell the viewmodel to load more data just do this `viewModel.loadMore(..)` in the `onScrolled(..)` function

Comment: Use live paging adapter instead of this. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging

Comment: you can use SwipRefreshLayout, with bottom refresh. https://www.journaldev.com/10708/android-swiperefreshlayout-pull-swipe-refresh

Answer (score 0):

Create your own scroll listener.

```
public abstract class EndlessScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    private int visibleThreshold = 2;
    private int currentPage = 1;
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    // it can LinearLayoutManager as well
    public EndlessScrollListener(GridLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
        visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView view, int dx, int dy) {
        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        }

        if (!loading && (lastVisibleItemPosition + visibleThreshold) > totalItemCount) {
            currentPage++;
            onLoadMore(currentPage, totalItemCount, view);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view);

}
```

In Fragment class

```
private void observeEndlessScrolling() {
        scrollListener = new EndlessScrollListener(layoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {

                    viewModel.fetchMoreData(page);
                } 
            }
        };
       recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
    }
```

https://github.com/droiddevgeeks/ImageSearch/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/imagesearch/ui/MainActivity.java

https://github.com/droiddevgeeks/ImageSearch/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/imagesearch/util/EndlessScrollListener.java

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment

```
yourViewModel.getDataFromUrl().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<Slider>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<YourDataType> datasServer) {
                //when data changes you get here...so notify adapter accordingly
            }
        });
```

this will observe data change in your ViewModel

In your ViewModel create this data type

```
private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<YourDataType>> data;
private ArrayList<YourDataType> serverDatas= new ArrayList<>();
```

Now, create getDataFromUrl() in your viewModel and inside your

response(...) from server create a loop and add data to AttayList serverDatas:

```
YourDataType yourDataType = new YourDataType(....);

serverDatas.add(yourDataType);
```

finally

```
data.setValue(serverDatas);
```